# PHP cURL error The URL was not properly formatted

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to do a simple cURL file upload from one server to another.  The problem is I get Error #3 from the cUrl error codes:  The URL was not properly formatted.

I have copied the url into my browser and logged onto the ftp site without a problem.  I have also verified the proper formatting and searched the web and this site for an answer without any success.

Here's the code:

```
$ch = curl_init();

$localfile = '/home/httpd/vhosts/homeserver.com/httpdocs/admin.php';  
echo $localfile;  //This reads back to proper path to the file
$fp = fopen($localfile, 'r');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'ftp://username:password@199.38.215.1xx/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($localfile));
curl_exec ($ch);
$error_no = curl_errno($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
if ($error_no == 0) {
  $error = 'File uploaded succesfully.';
} else {
  $error  = 'Upload error:'.$error_no ;//Error codes explained here http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html';
}
echo $error;
```

I have also tried this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'ftp://199.38.215.1xx/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'username:password');
```

I still get error #3.

Any ideas?

Comment: PHP has built in FTP functions that may work better than cURL.

Answer (score 0):

your remote URL needs to contain the path and name of the destination file, as shown in this [example](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/php/examples/ftpupload.html)

```
<?php
// FTP upload to a remote site Written by Daniel Stenberg
// original found at http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/php/examples/ftpupload.html
//
// A simple PHP/CURL FTP upload to a remote site
//

$localfile = "me-and-my-dog.jpg";
$ftpserver = "ftp.mysite.com";
$ftppath   = "/path/to";
$ftpuser   = "myname";
$ftppass   = "mypass";

$remoteurl = "ftp://${ftpuser}:${ftppasswd}@${ftpserver}${ftppath}/${localfile}";

$ch = curl_init();

$fp = fopen($localfile, "rb");

// we upload a JPEG image
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $remoteurl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);

// set size of the image, which isn't _mandatory_ but helps libcurl to do
// extra error checking on the upload.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($localfile));

$error = curl_exec($ch);

// check $error here to see if it did fine or not!

curl_close($ch); 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example - I'm a little closer.  I modified the example to echo the error code and get error 9:  "We were denied access to the resource given in the URL. For FTP, this occurs while trying to change to the remote directory."    I've tried a different ftp site on the same server and made sure the permissions were correct (I can ftp to it without trouble), so I don't know where to turn next.

Comment: what do your ftp server (error-)logs say? Are you authenticated (and as the correct user?), does the remote directory exist, is it writable and readable by the authenticated user,..?